# set react state after props get the value from redux state(which is axios request in action and ReduxPromise in Midleware)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I have component that gets props from the redux state with connect function. However my Redux state is a ReduxPromise when this component starts so if I assign this.state = {books: this.props.books} in the constructor I obviously get an error.
I tried

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
   this.setState({books: nextProps.books});
}
```

but in this case I get "Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded", my browser freeze for like 2-3 seconds and only then books displayed. 
Is there way I can assign props to the react state(I need it to manipulate with the filters and pass it to child components) directly after the promise was resolved and this.props.books has real values?

Action:

```
//get all books from server
export function getBooksData() {

    const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/db/`);

    return{
        type: GET_BOOKS,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { all: [] };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){

    switch (action.type){

        case GET_BOOKS:         
            return {...state, all: action.payload.data}; 
    }

    return state;
}
```

Component:

```
class BooksIndex extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        /* getting list of books with the action creator */
        this.props.getBooksData();

        this.state = {books: this.props.books};


        //if filters change state parent component should update the RenderBooks props
        //filter state, needed to update component on filter update
        var handleToUpdate  = this.handleToUpdate.bind(this);
        this.state = {filterSwitcher: true};
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){          
        this.setState({books: nextProps.books});
    } 

    handleToUpdate(someArg){
        this.setState({filterSwitcher: someArg});
        this.setState({books: this.props.books});
        console.log(this.props.books);
    }



    render(){       

        return(
            <div className="row">

                {/* sortig component */}
                <SortFilters handleToUpdate = {this.handleToUpdate.bind(this)}></SortFilters>

                { this.state.books == undefined ? <Preloader /> : <RenderBooks books={this.state.books} />}

            </div>          
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){

    return {
        books: state.books.all.books
    }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getBooksData})(BooksIndex);
```

Comment: can you show where do you return the promise and action itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

This code:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
  this.setState({books: nextProps.books});
}
```

Is an infinite recursion. Calling `this.setState` will call `componentWillUpdate`.

You have to do something else. For instance:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return this.state.books !== nextState.books;
}
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
  this.setState({books: nextProps.books});
}
```

Comment: return this.state.books !== nextState.books; should be return this.state.books !== nextProps.books; as at the beginning both states are empty but yes, you are correct, this was an infinite recursion, thank you:)